# Time needed for comparisons to return vs just returning True or False

Tags: python, time, comparison, asymptotic-complexity

I'm having trouble understanding why one version of my code takes twice as long as the other. They both person the same function which is to return `True` if the number passed in is a palindrome, otherwise return `False`. The first version averages about 1.5 seconds to return `True` or `False`, while the second takes about .75 seconds on average.

1st Version: Uses a comparison:

```
def isPalindrome(num):
    number = str(num)
    count = 0
    for letter in number:
        if letter is number[len(number) - count - 1]:
            count += 1
    return count == len(number)
```

2nd version: Uses an else statement:

```
def isPalindrome(num):
    number = str(num)
    count = 0
    for letter in number:
        if letter is number[len(number) - count - 1]:
            count += 1
         else:
             return False
    return True
```

Comment: What is puzzling about an early out being faster?

Answer (score 0):

On a palindrome, the two functions are equivalent: They take same number n steps. If the palindrome breaks early on, 2nd function returns way earlier, while the 1st keeps incrementing the `count` till the string's last element.

Example:

```
"abcdefgh1234554321hgfedcba" -> both take n steps.
"bcdefgh1234554321hgfedcba" -> 2nd takes 1 step and return, while 1st takes n steps.
```

Answer (score -1):

The first code version always checks all the digits, even if it knows the number can't be a palindrome.

The second code version doesn't do that.